# Configuring wacom tablet on Ubuntu 12.10 by installing missing dependencies

Tags: 12.10, xorg, dependencies, gimp, wacom

I've been reading a book on Gimp.  The book recommended that I visit the [LinuxWacom Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/) for the drivers of a Wacom tablet I own.

After extracting the tarball, I have to configure and make install.  But this part is where ./configure got interesting.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (xorg-server >= 1.7.0 xproto xext kbproto inputproto randrproto) were not met:

No package 'xorg-server' found
No package 'xproto' found
No package 'xext' found
No package 'kbproto' found
No package 'inputproto' found
No package 'randrproto' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XORG_CFLAGS
and XORG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
john@kotux:~/xf86-input-wacom-0.20.0$
```

Not to mention my laptop on 12.10 has Xorg version 1.13.0.  Not right.

I thought it was as simple as installing the missing dependencies via apt-get, but they didn't work.

```
john@kotux:~/xf86-input-wacom-0.20.0$ sudo apt-get install xorg-server xproto xext 
kbproto inputproto randrproto
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xorg-server
E: Unable to locate package xproto
E: Unable to locate package xext
E: Unable to locate package kbproto
E: Unable to locate package inputproto
E: Unable to locate package randrproto
```

How can I install these missing packages? I wish the process does not require much manual installation.

Comment: Eh..  That looks *pretty* old.  Have you tried configuring it via System Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How old is the book?

I've been using GIMP on Ubuntu for 6+ years now. Even just a few years back, there were tons of configuration problems getting a Wacom tablet set up properly on Ubuntu (especially with dual-monitor setups).

Since 12.04 and 12.10, though, I have not had a single problem with Wacom tablets in Ubuntu. The automatic configuration works perfectly for me, even with my dual-monitor layout.

Try using the Wacom tablet settings in the regular System Settings application for Ubuntu. Unless you have a strange hardware configuration, there shouldn't be any need to install the driver yourself.

If you are having issues in GIMP specifically but not in other programs (try out Krita, MyPaint, etc.) then you can try editing the Input Device settings in GIMP to make sure that your tablet is not set to "disabled" in the program.

Either way, your tablet *should* work out of the box with the most recent versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

You need a lot of -dev packages to compile this. Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev libxext-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxi-dev libudev-dev
```

Comment: This worked for me with the same issues.

Comment: I'm getting a permissions error that sudo cant solve....

Comment: @SumNeuron no one will be able to help you unless you say what that error is.. (I assume it's solved now.. but for the future).